# what is the purpose of {content} inside an html code?

Tags: html

`<div id="main-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            {content}
        </div><!-- end container -->
    </div><!-- end main-wrap -->`

What is the purpose of {content} here. what is it doing ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H2xJj/ Simply just filler until you add real content.

Comment: also used by some templating engines, so it is compiled and replaced with real code/data on runtime

Comment: so how does that work, everything after <div id="container"> and before </div> gets erased and replaced with actual code at run time?  what if i have some code written inside <div id="container"> and </div>, does that get erased automatically ?

Comment: yes, u'll need to put the code somewhere else, or put it on the actual code that is used to generate the actual content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It acts as a placeholder.

Mostly used by templating engines.